# Check if tag/class exists several tags down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this layout, and I want to check the innerHTML of the .pricecolor class while cycling through each .productnamcolor class:

```
<tr>
    <td valign="top" width="33%">
        <div>
            **<a href="http://www.site.com/Prodcut1.htm" class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Product 1">**
            <span itemprop='name'>
            Product 1 </span>
            </a>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <div>
                    **<b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n">$16.00</span></font></b>**
                </div>
                <img src="Shipping_Small.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="33%">
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.site.com/Product2.htm" class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Product 2">
            <span itemprop='name'>
            Product 2 </span>
            </a>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n">$9.00</span></font></b>
                </div>
                <img src="Shipping_Small.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
    </td>
    <td valign="top" width="33%">
        <div>
            <a href="http://www.site.com/Product3.htm" class="productnamecolor colors_productname" title="Product 3">
            <span itemprop='name'>
            Product 3 </span>
            </a>
            <br/>
            <div>
                <div>
                    <b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"><span class="PageText_L483n">$8.00</span></font></b>
                </div>
                <img src="Shipping_Small.gif">
            </div>
        </td>
    </td>
</tr>
```

There are 3 repetitions here, and I've put asterisks around the two relevant lines of the first one. These asterisks are not in the real code.

Here's the jQuery I've tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.productnamecolor').each(function() {
          var test = $('.pricecolor').innerHTML;
          console.log(test);
     });
});
```

I've also tried:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('.productnamecolor').each(function() {
          var test = $(this).closest('b').innerHTML;
          console.log(test);
     });
});
```

Both of these always tell the console it's undefined.

What I really need is, sometimes in one of these HTML product blocks, the `<span class="PageText_L483n">$8.00</span>` is entirely missing from the `<b><font class="pricecolor colors_productprice"> </font></b>`. THAT'S what I need to check with the jQuery.

Comment: Use the selector API, not `innerHTML`. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+check+element+exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your selection is incorrect, you need to look for `pricecolor` of the respective `productnamecolor` section.

try

```
 $('.productnamecolor').each(function() {
      var test = $(this).closest('div').find('.pricecolor').html();
      console.log(test);
 });
```

Confused reading your last statement, if you want to find all .productnamecolor that doesn't have the span with the classname you can do:

```
$('.pricecolor:not(:has(".PageText_L483n"))')
                 .closest('td')
                 .find('.productnamecolor');
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pL289/)**

Comment: Your first bit of code there solves my problem. Question though, why doesn't my second jQuery code `var test = $(this).closest('b').innerHTML;` work? Isn't it doing the same thing as yours, which is finding the closest instance of that particular tag?

Comment: @user1925805 closest tests itself up to the DOM tree, i.e its parents or itself, but `b` is no where there.